# Add two columns one below other in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a big DataFrame and I`m trying to transform 2 columns(Series) into 1.

Example:

```
print(df['col1'])
0 1
1 2
2 3
```

```
print(df['col2'])
0 7
1 8
2 9
```

Output:

```
print(df['singleCol'])
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 7
4 8
5 9
```

Is this possible using Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
series1 = pd.Series(df['col1'])
series2 = pd.Series(df['col2'])
df = pd.concat([series1, series2], axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df.stack().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 1, 2, 3], 'col2': [7, 8, 9, 9]})
```

output:

```
0    1
1    7
2    8
3    2
4    9
5    3
dtype: int64
```

###### alternative for a subset of columns:

```
df.melt('col3', value_name='singleCol').drop_duplicates('singleCol').drop(columns='variable')
```

example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 1, 2, 3], 'col2': [7, 8, 9, 9], 'col3': list('ABCD')})
```

output:

```
  col3  singleCol
0    A          1
2    C          2
3    D          3
4    A          7
5    B          8
6    C          9
```

Comment: The DataFrame has other columns

Comment: @null92 then provide a clean reproducible example (as DataFrame constructor, like in my answer) ;)

Comment: The numbers was just to give an example, the DataFrame has 50k columns =/

Comment: still, please provide a minimal example, it's impossible to know what you want otherwise

Comment: Is it understandable now?

Comment: It doesn't change much. Let's take it the other way around, does my answer address your question? If not, why?

Comment: Well, I'm not a pro, so I can't solve my problem with your solution :/

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't understand your problem if you don't give a clear example. The one you gave can be solved by my answer.

Comment: I just want to stack two differente columns into one from a DataFrame.

Comment: That not a sufficient description. What happens to the other columns? Have you checked the second part of my answer?

Comment: I don't need the other columns. I only have to exctract and stack these couple columns.

Comment: I found a way!!!

Comment: Then my answer should work for you `df[['col1', 'col2']].stack().drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)`